# How to change the default separator of my list items?

Tags: css, menu, separator, divider

In my style.css I have:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}
```

This causes my menu to display:
Home  |  About  |  Blog  |  Shop  |

I would like it to display: 
Home  /  About  /  Blog  /  Shop

Does anyone have any hints for me? I tried:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: #fff;
   content: "/" rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

But that just made the separators disappear altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `position:absolute` at all as it's overkill (albeit not very much overkill). You can use floats instead:

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px; /* Adjust as needed */
}
li:not(:first-of-type):after { /* Exempts the first LI */
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px; /* Adjust as needed */
    content:"/";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Show</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```